# change event on <select> Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, drop-down-menu, meteor

I know that Meteor supports events and I have seen it in action on checkboxes, but I just wanted someone to be able clarify if we can hook change events in meteor on select dropdowns as like the following

```
 Template.templateName.events({
     'change select': function(e,t){
        // do whatever.......
     }
 });
```

I am trying to do this using Meteor and it doesn't seem to be firing when I change the value in the select box. However when I use jQuery to change things then it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work, it works fine for me.

Though I think events only take one eventMap-argument, not two. What would the "t" argument be?

Comment: Kristoffer K: According to some of the tutorials i have been following   I think the t represents some targeted element possibly when the reactive part of meteor changes. In regards to the select code working fine, strange I have tried it again and again even on different parts and it still doesn't pick up the change event at all. Anyway thanks for answering.

Comment: OK, I use event.currentTarget to get the current target. I think that's the "correct" way to do it. Or do you mean some other element than the clicked/changed/whatever one? Thank you!

Comment: second parameter can be used to get the related template data through t.data, for example when you're using {{#each users}}{{>itemRow}}{{/each}} you can listen to events in template itemRow and use t.data to get the user associated with the row

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event like this to handle multiple checkboxes, then check some property (often id) to see which one was clicked. Or here since `this` returns my client row, I can just get the value I want from the context.

Template fragment:

```
 {{#each phonemeResults}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="star">
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          {{word}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <small>{{phoneme}}</small>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

Event handler:

```
Template.phonemeList.events({
  'change [type=checkbox]': function(e, t){
    console.log("add " + this.word + " to user's public starred list");
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. The gotcha was that only the `<option>` elements were included in my template, and the `<select>` element was in outside it, in `<body>`. Make sure that the Template the event map is configured actually contains the `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fire on a specific select box change:

```
Template.chatRooms.events({
'change #chatroomList' : function(event){
        console.log("Changed")
      }
})
```

If you want it to fire on any selectbox change in the template:

```
Template.chatRooms.events({
    'change select' : function(event){
            console.log("Changed")
          }
    })
```